# Python： checks if any one of them is equal to the sum of the other two

Tags: python

I have a question on class about checks if any one of them is equal to the sum of the other two. This is function I have right now. The result always return True, why it can't return False ?

```
def any_one_is_sum(a,b,c):
    sum_c=a+b
    sum_b=a+c
    sum_a=b+c
    if sum_c == a+b:
        if sum_b == c+a:
            if sum_a == b+c:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

I guess I may got bug on somewhere, but I can't find it...

Comment: You are defining the variables `sum_c=a+b` then testing `if sum_c==a+b` these are all true by definition. Maybe you just want `return c == a+b or b == c+a or a == b+c`?

Comment: I got you. But if I try to not define variables, it shows that sum_c not defined.

Comment: Notice there's no `sum_c` in this line: `return c == a+b or b == c+a or a == b+c` therefor there should not be an error. You don't need those variables.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get you, are you talking about I should change the return values?( not True and False)